# Adding Cipher Suite to Android/Harmony Jsse

Tags: android, ssl, jsse

So Harmony JSSE doesn't have the ciphersuite that I need to connect to my server. It has no support for TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA. Is it possible (and if so, how) to add in support for that suite? I have the source for harmony JSSE, can I just add in the code for that cipher suite? Is there an easier way to add it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it's been long enough and I finally figured it out.

There is a library, SpongyCastle that is basically the full BouncyCastle for android. It has the proper ciphersuite that I need.